# cannot see settings app when in kiosk mode

Tags: kiosk-mode, android-management-api

We have integrated Android management API into our solution. We have a problem that when the device is put into multi-app kiosk, we cannot get access to the settings app.

Once in kiosk we apply ("DeviceSettings": "SETTINGS_ACCESS_ALLOWED") but there is nothing apparent where we can get to the settings app.

The only way we could find to get to the Settings in KM was to do the following :

Enable NOTIFICATIONS > pull NOTIFICATIONS down > tap NOTIFICATIONS SETTINGS at the bottom right > hit the BackSpace (<-)

button at the top > THEN you can see SETTINGS!

Whilst neither of these issues is "the end of the world" , could we please have some confirmation if
1)that this is how this functionality is intended to work
2) if it is just possibly a quirk of the A10 , or 3) is there is something else that we are missing?

thankyou

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To enable [kioskcustomization.deviceSettings.SETTINGS_ACCESS_ALLOWED](https://developers.google.com/android/management/reference/rest/v1/enterprises.policies#DeviceSettings), you need to do the following:

1. Set [kioskCustomLauncherEnabled](https://developers.google.com/android/management/reference/rest/v1/enterprises.policies#KioskCustomization:%7E:text=kioskCustomLauncherEnabled-,boolean,alphabetical%20order.%20Use%20kioskCustomization%20to%20further%20configure%20the%20kiosk%20device%20behavior.,-skipFirstUseHintsEnabled) to true.
2. Add the "com.android.settings" app to the application policy.

Once you have done these steps, the user will be able to access the Settings app from the launcher.

Comment: thanks for the answer.  am i correct in thinking that com.android.settings will always be the native android app package name on all devices?

Comment: Hello again,  Ok we will add com.android.settings to the application policy. However can you please confirm that all devices from all manufacturers will have access to com.android.Settings. For example, with Samsung devices, isn't the native Settings app com.samsung.Settings? Could we just add the android flavour to the application policy as default, then if it fails on a particular device, then we could use our MDM to install a 3rd party settings app instead? (from the managed google play)